# Error: ORA-04043: object table name does not exist when describing any table within a specific user workstation from the SQL command line

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have created tables in Oracle DB from the SQL command line, and I'm having a problem when describing the table, when going through the oracle application express web page I can see them there.

The oracle version I have is the following:
 SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production

The following is the command I used to create a table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE  "Product" 
(   "ProuctID" VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ProductExpiryDate" DATE, 
    "CustomerID" VARCHAR2(8), 
     CONSTRAINT "Product_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ProductID") ENABLE
) ;
```

Command for describing the table:

`Desc Product;`

But at the end after creating each table and describe it I get this:
ORA-04043: object Product does not exist

Can anyone please tell me why I am I getting this, when I can see it in Oracle Xpress web page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By enclosing the table name in double quotes, you created the table with a case-sensitive name. To correctly specify the name, you now have to *always* enclose it in double quotes.

So instead of `Desc Product`, you need `Desc "Product"`.

Because this is quite cumbersome and error-prone, it's usually best to avoid enclosing table and column names in double quotes in the first place. If possible, I'd recommend you either drop & recreate the table or rename it.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me a lot I am now able to see me tables!