# ORA-04043 on Insert

Tags: java, jooq

We are trying to store a record:

```
DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.ORACLE12C);
KampartikelRecord kampartikelRecord = dsl.newRecord(KAMPARTIKEL);
kampartikelRecord.setKampagne(387);
kampartikelRecord.setArtnr("090248");
kampartikelRecord.setArtId(5558);
kampartikelRecord.store();
```

But we get:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "TOSCA"."KAMPARTIKEL" ("KAMPAGNE", "ART_ID", "ARTNR") values (?, ?, ?)]; ORA-04043: Objekt "TOSCA" ist nicht vorhanden
    at org.jooq_3.12.1.ORACLE12C.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2717)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:755)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:383)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert0(TableRecordImpl.java:206)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl$1.operate(TableRecordImpl.java:177)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:130)
    at org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl.storeInsert(TableRecordImpl.java:173)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store0(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:196)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl$1.operate(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:136)
    at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:130)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:132)
    at org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl.store(UpdatableRecordImpl.java:124)
    at ch.tosca.common.repository.JooqRepositoryTest.insertKampartikel(JooqRepositoryTest.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: Objekt "TOSCA" ist nicht vorhanden
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:456)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:451)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1040)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odsy.doODSY(T4C8Odsy.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Odsy.doODSYTable(T4C8Odsy.java:126)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doDescribeTable(T4CConnection.java:5168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:4654)
    at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:136)
    at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:125)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.prepare0(AbstractDMLQuery.java:859)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.prepare(AbstractDMLQuery.java:754)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:336)
    ... 48 more
```

I've read a GitHub issue about driver incompatibility but Database and Driver ojdbc8 both are version 12.2.0.1.0

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: And the `TOSCA` schema does exist for sure? And it's named `TOSCA`, not `Tosca` or `tosca` ([why I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515173/error-ora-04043-object-table-name-does-not-exist-when-describing-any-table-wit))?

Comment: No everything is correct. There is a similar issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7962 It just doesn't work with that particular Record

Comment: Which database driver and version are you using? ojdbc8?

Comment: The issue link states that they were using "Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production", so a later version than you have. Have you tried the latest version of JOOQ to see if it works? If not, then I recommend you create a new issue with them.

Comment: I'm using the latest version.

Comment: One situation where I have encountered this problem is when there is a schema-level object in the current schema with the same name as the schema. So if there is an object called `TOSCA` in the current schema (of your database session), then you will have trouble referring to objects in the `TOSCA` schema.

Comment: That's not the case. And with ojdbc7 everything works fine.

Comment: Can you also add an exception stack trace to your question? Also, did you try `ctx.configuration().settings().setReturnIdentityOnUpdatableRecord(false)`? This may of course not be what you want...

Comment: I added the full stacktrace. And we must have the identity that is returned. So setting this to false is not an option

Comment: Does the user under which your application is running have access to this schema in DB?

Comment: Yes everything works with ojdbc7

Comment: Can you generate unqualified table names? Via `Settings.renderSchema` If I remember correctly, that's a viable workaround for this Oracle bug.

Comment: I could try. Which Oracle bug is this? Is it documented?

Comment: @LukasEder If I set withRenderSchema(false) I get the ORA-00904 in a order by clause. Which is very strange.

Comment: @LukasEder So the whole statement has no TOSCA but the order by has the schema name included

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Interesting, that would definitely be a bug. Mind reporting it here? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. We'll soon release 3.12.2. This can probably be included. However, I meant to set that setting only specifically for this kind of statement, unless you don't really need the schema? I haven't been able to track down the MOS ID of the bug, but this is a known issue, see e.g. https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, which has been reported a few times:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7962
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/FXK3A6_RrDM/zMQ35mjyBwAJ

I'm still not 100% sure what Oracle server or JDBC bug causes it, but it can be avoided either by not qualifying the table with the schema name, or by avoiding to quote the schema name. Here's how to reproduce it with plain JDBC:

#### How to reproduce it

Using this table

```sql
CREATE TABLE T (
  ID NUMBER(7),
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Use the `Connection.prepareStatement(String, String[])` overload, such as jOOQ does, internally:

```java
try (Connection c = dbSetup.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(
        "insert into \"TEST\".\"T\" (\"ID\") values (?)", new String[] { "ID" })) {
        s.setInt(1, 1);
        s.execute ();
    }
}
```

#### Workarounds

Don't quote the schema name:

```java
try (Connection c = dbSetup.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(
        "insert into TEST.\"T\" (\"ID\") values (?)", new String[] { "ID" })) {
        s.setInt(1, 1);
        s.execute ();
    }
}
```

Avoid the qualification entirely:

```java
try (Connection c = dbSetup.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement(
        "insert into \"T\" (\"ID\") values (?)", new String[] { "ID" })) {
        s.setInt(1, 1);
        s.execute ();
    }
}
```

#### Using the workarounds in jOOQ:

- You can turn off schema qualification using `Settings.renderSchema`
- You can turn off quoting of identifiers using `Settings.renderQuotedNames`

We'll finally fix this in jOOQ via https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7962

I've also created a discussion on the Oracle community channel for JDBC:
https://community.oracle.com/message/15550855#15550855